# How to remove duplicate items in a ListView?

Tags: delphi, duplicates, tlistview

I have a `TListView` with some items in it:

```
item1
item1
item2
```

I want to remove duplicate items when I click on a button:

```
item1
item2
```

Here is my code so far:

```pascal
procedure TMainForm.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var i,j, k: integer;
begin
  I := 0;
  while I < ListView1.Items.Count  do
  begin
    for j := ListView1.Items.Count - 1 downto 0 do
    begin
      if ListView1.Items[I].SubItems[3] = ListView1.Items[j].SubItems[3] then
        ListView1.Items.Delete(J);
        Continue;
       end;
       Inc(I);
  end;
end;
```

It's deleting all items. How can I fix this?

Comment: Shouldn't you be increasing value of `I` using `Inc` method and not `J`? In your case `J` is control variable of your `for loo` and this it is managed by `for loop` mechanism. Your `while loop` is dependent of `I` variable and thus you should be manually updating your `I` variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The items are not deleted immediately when you call `Delete()`. The `ListView` must return to the message loop for the items to actually become deleted. Therefore, if you have the same item on e.g. line 1 and line 4, both lines will deleted:

- line 4 when `i=1` and `j=4`
- line 1 when `i=4` and `j=1`

This is fixed by changing the `for j := ...` loop to:

```
for j := ListView1.Items.Count - 1 downto i+1 do // instead of downto 0
```

That ensures that a pair of line is compared only once, and that the latter of two equal lines is removed.

Comment: im understand thks !